# How to get average of column of other table

Tags: mysql

I have other table called "resource_ratings" that has resource_id as foreign key and column to register ratings called "rating_level". I need to get AVG of rating_level column. but I think I am doing something wrong. so I copied the working query without getting AVG so you can start from working query and get that extra data.

```
SELECT 
    a.company_id,
    a.company_code,
    a.company_name,
    a.company_name_s,
    b.resource_id,
    b.resource_code,
    b.resource_name,
    b.resource_name_s,
    b.spec_id,
    b.resource_description,
    b.resource_description_s,
    d.slot_id,
    d.slot_period_minutes,
    d.slot_desc,
    e.res_slot,
    e.from_time,
    e.to_time,
    e.slot_date
FROM
    companies a,
    resources b,
    resource_periods c,
    period_slots d,
    resource_slots e
WHERE
    a.company_id = b.company_id
        AND a.is_active = 1
        AND b.is_active = 1
        AND b.company_id = c.company_id
        AND b.resource_id = c.resource_id
        AND c.allow_publish = 1
        AND c.company_id = d.company_id
        AND c.resource_id = d.resource_id
        AND c.period_id = d.period_id
        AND d.is_active = 1
        AND d.company_id = e.company_id
        AND d.resource_id = e.resource_id
        AND d.period_id = e.period_id
        AND d.slot_id = e.slot_id
        AND e.slot_status = 1
        AND a.company_id = IFNULL(@company_id, a.company_id)
        AND a.country_id = @country_id
        AND a.city_id = @city_id
        AND b.resource_id IN (SELECT 
            f.resource_id
        FROM
            resource_specialities f
        WHERE
            b.resource_id = f.resource_id
                AND f.spec_id = @speciality_id)
        AND e.slot_date = @slot_date
```

Comment: "resource_id as foreign key" - What is it referencing?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel resource_id in resources table

Comment: I think best way for this query would be to use a correlated subquery in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I believe MySQL does better with joins than correlated subqueries.

Comment: @Barmar I've seen many cases where it doesn't. "It depends"

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that gets the average. You need to change your cross product syntax to explict `JOIN`, so you can use a `LEFT JOIN` here (in case there are no matching rows in the subquery).

```
SELECT 
    a.company_id,
    a.company_code,
    a.company_name,
    a.company_name_s,
    b.resource_id,
    b.resource_code,
    b.resource_name,
    b.resource_name_s,
    b.spec_id,
    b.resource_description,
    b.resource_description_s,
    d.slot_id,
    d.slot_period_minutes,
    d.slot_desc,
    e.res_slot,
    e.from_time,
    e.to_time,
    e.slot_date,
    f.avg_rating
FROM companies a
JOIN resources b ON a.company_id = b.company_id
JOIN resource_periods c 
    ON b.company_id = c.company_id 
    AND b.resource_id = c.resource_id
JOIN period_slots d 
    ON c.company_id = d.company_id
    AND c.resource_id = d.resource_id
    AND c.period_id = d.period_id
JOIN resource_slots e
    ON d.company_id = e.company_id
    AND d.resource_id = e.resource_id
    AND d.period_id = e.period_id
    AND d.slot_id = e.slot_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT resource_id, AVG(rating_level) AS avg_rating
    FROM resource_ratings
    GROUP BY resource_id) AS f
    ON f.resource_id = b.resource_id
WHERE
    a.is_active = 1
    AND b.is_active = 1
    AND c.allow_publish = 1
    AND d.is_active = 1
    AND e.slot_status = 1
    AND a.company_id = IFNULL(@company_id, a.company_id)
    AND a.country_id = @country_id
    AND a.city_id = @city_id
    AND b.resource_id IN (SELECT 
        f.resource_id
        FROM
            resource_specialities f
        WHERE
            b.resource_id = f.resource_id
                AND f.spec_id = @speciality_id)
    AND e.slot_date = @slot_date
```

Comment: thanks, but it returns many rows almost with same data http://i.imgur.com/bmsbjqd.png

Comment: That's because there are multiple matching rows with the other tables. I don't think my change can cause duplicate rows.

Comment: Note that the subquery (derived table) is unfiltered. And then you are doing a LEFT JOIN with (probably) an unindexed temp table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Good point. If the main query does extensive filtering, the correlated subquery in RMathis's answer might work better.

Comment: There might be an even better way. If we know that the original query retuns exactly one row per `resource_id` you wouldn't need a subquery. But again - sometimes MySQL performs very poorly on multiple JOINS + LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY even though everything is perfectly indexed.

Comment: it's still returning multiple rows :\

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I didn't want to put the `GROUP BY` in the main query, because then you run into the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` issue.

Comment: @dotfreelancer Does your original query return multiple rows? The subquery only returns 1 row per resource ID, so it can't multiply the number of rows in the result.

Comment: @Barmar it suppose to return only one row for the resource. original query was returning one row. but in ratings table, there are multiple rows per resource_id.. that's why it returns multiple rows

Comment: @dotfreelancer But the subquery has `GROUP BY resource_id`, so it just returns one row for each `resource_id`. Look at the other columns in your output, they're different on each row, which means you have multiple matches in the other joins.

Comment: You're getting `res_slot = 11` and `res_slot = 12` and `res_slot = 13`, that means there are multiple matches in `resource_slots`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    a.company_id,
    a.company_code,
    a.company_name,
    a.company_name_s,
    b.resource_id,
    b.resource_code,
    b.resource_name,
    b.resource_name_s,
    b.spec_id,
    b.resource_description,
    b.resource_description_s,
    (select avg(rating_level)
       from resource_ratings
      where resource_id = b.resource_id ) as avg_rating_level,
    d.slot_id,
    d.slot_period_minutes,
    d.slot_desc,
    e.res_slot,
    e.from_time,
    e.to_time,
    e.slot_date
FROM
    companies a,
    resources b,
    resource_periods c,
    period_slots d,
    resource_slots e,
    resource_specialities f
WHERE
    a.company_id = b.company_id
        AND a.is_active = 1
        AND b.is_active = 1
        AND b.company_id = c.company_id
        AND b.resource_id = c.resource_id
        AND c.allow_publish = 1
        AND c.company_id = d.company_id
        AND c.resource_id = d.resource_id
        AND c.period_id = d.period_id
        AND d.is_active = 1
        AND d.company_id = e.company_id
        AND d.resource_id = e.resource_id
        AND d.period_id = e.period_id
        AND d.slot_id = e.slot_id
        AND e.slot_status = 1
        AND a.company_id = IFNULL(@company_id, a.company_id)
        AND a.country_id = @country_id
        AND a.city_id = @city_id
        AND b.resource_id = f.resource_id
        AND f.spec_id = @speciality_id
        AND e.slot_date = @slot_date
```

Comment: Note that you can not always replace an IN subquery with a JOIN. You might need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` in this case.